# on Mac, scroll-down or scroll-up don't move point to very top/bottom

Tags: scrolling

I'm fairly new to the Mac, and I've started using Emacs. I've noticed that the scroll-down command, bound to Meta-v, works okay to scroll the visible portion of the buffer, except that it doesn't move point to the very top of the buffer, the behavior that I'm used to in Windows. Nor does Ctrl-v move point to the very bottom of the buffer. Why is this, and how can I change it to match Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling doesn't move point, unless it has to because point would otherwise be outside the window.

The Emacs manual, node [Scrolling](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scrolling.html) explains this and more.

As you can see there, you can control how much overlap there is when you scroll a "windowful", using option `next-screen-context-lines`.

And you can customize option **`scroll-error-top-bottom`** to `t` to get the behavior you are used to: `M-x customize-option scroll-error-top-bottom`.

As you are fairly new to Emacs, here is the first and *most important* thing to learn: ***Ask Emacs***.

**`C-h r`** puts you in the Emacs manual, which is hypertext linked. When in a manual, you can use **`i`** and type some text plus `TAB` to complete, to look something up in the index and go to it in the manual.

In this case, I did `C-h r`, then `i scroll TAB`, and I chose the index entry `scrolling`, which took me directly to the node (page) of the manual cited above.

**`C-h C-h`** is the general Help entry point (all help commands use the prefix `C-h`). Try it, to learn more about how to **ask Emacs**.